# Is it possible to run through several states in one statechart at the same time?

Tags: state, anylogic, agent-based-modeling, statechart

Is it possible to run through several states in one statechart at the same time?

My simulation model is agent-based.

A) At the moment I consider my process as a continuous chain for simplicity. This means that only when the product is ejected from the machine can the process restart. The individual stations of the machine are represented as states.

B) Now I would like to represent the following: The machine should be able to run through several states simultaneously in one run. Example: If the manufactured product is just ejected from the machine, there is raw material in the filling station and in the pressing station at the same time. This means that more product is produced in the best possible time than when I look at the process as in A.

I would be glad about any help. :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. Really not clear what you are actually asking. A better explanation of the process would help, and most importantly: screenshots :-)

Answer (score 0):

Three axioms that are always true, and you must make your logic follow them:

1. an agent can always only be in 1 state per state chart
2. While in 1 state, it can be part of a larger "composite state" (see [help](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?nav=%2F0_10_1))
3. An agent can have several state charts running in parallel, for example one for "machine states" and one for "failure states"

Be careful with point 3, though. If you have several state charts in 1 agent type, they should be 100% mutually exclusive, i.e. represent *very* different things.